# Is it theoretically possible that every person in this village has a different jar of coins?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A village has about $1$ million residents. Suppose each resident
has a jar with $100$ coins in it.Two jars are considered to be “equivalent” if they have the same number of 10c, 20c, 50c, $\$$1 and $\$$2 coins in them.
How many different (i.e. nonequivalent) jars of coins exist? Is it
theoretically possible that every person in this village has a different
jar of coins?

I understood that if we have $k_1$ 10 coins in the jar where $k_1$ is between $0$ and $100$ inclusive, then there are $100-k_1$ coins of other denominations in the jar. Likewise, we also have $k_2$ 20c coins in the jar where $k_2$ is between $0$ and $100$ inclusive, so the combined number of 50c, $\$$1, and $\$$2 coins in the jar is $100-k_1-k_2$. And we always have some $k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4, k_5$, let's say, so that the sum of those $k$'s is $100$.

I got stuck since I don't know how to 'compare' the number of coins in jars for different residents.

Comment: A village with a million inhabitants is a large town.

Comment: It's a hypothetical assumption haha

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into difficulties?

Comment: I understood that if we have k1 10c coins in the jar where k1 is between 0 and 100 inclusive, then there are 100-k1 coins of other denominations in the jar. Likewise, we also have k2 20c coins in the jar where k2 is between 0 and 100 inclusive, so the combined number of 50c, $1, and $2 coins in the jar is 100-k1-k2. And we always have some k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, let's say, so that the sum of those k's is 100

Comment: I got stuck since I don't know how to 'compare' the number of coins in jars for different residents.

Comment: @EmilyTakawaki I agree with your comment that you're looking for the number of integer solutions to
$$
k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + k_4 + k_5 = 100
$$
you can use the stars and bars method for this. After this, the question is just to essentially compare this number to $1~000~000$ and see if it's bigger or smaller.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the result would be if the number found is bigger or smaller?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  You should include your attempt and an explanation of where you are stuck in the question itself rather than the comments, where they might be missed.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the non-negative solutions to following equation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{5} x_i = 100$$

Where $x_i$ represent the number of different coins in a jar. The problem can be solved using "Stars and Bars" method (Google this for an illustration). Considering $100$ stars and $4$ bars. These $4$ bars will partition the $100$ stars into $5$ portions which will represent the number of different coins in a jar. So therefore the total number of partitions that can be generated are:

$$\binom{104}{4}$$